# how to pass an element to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I would like to pass the form.find element to my function AvailabilityChecker. I tried to get the elements Attribute with no success. Whats wrong?

```
var AvailabilityChecker = function (ev, el) {   
       console.log("arguments: ",Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)); //gives: arguments:  Array [ Object ]
       console.log(ev);
       console.log("AvailabilityChecker: ",el.attr('AvailabilityChecker') //gives Typeerror
}


form.find("input[AvailabilityChecker]").keyup(AvailabilityChecker.bind(this));
```

Comment: Binding to `this`, the way you are, is using a completely different context. Why not just use `.keyup(AvailabilityChecker)` then, within that function, `this` will be your matching elements. Given it's jQuery you may want to call `this.first()` since it'll likely retrieve a set.

Comment: this.attr('AvailabilityChecker') gives: TypeError: this.attr is not a function

Comment: because `this` is not jQuery....

Comment: Why are you using `.bind(this)`?

Comment: Are you writing this impl or using an existing one (in other words can you change AvailabilityChecker's signature or has to be as-is)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `el` is not going to be an attribute magically appended as an argument. So you need to do it another way. And using .bind() is also changes how you can get the element reference

```js
var AvailabilityChecker = function (ev) {  
  console.log("1-DOM", ev.target.getAttribute("AvailabilityChecker"))
  console.log("1-JQ",$(ev.target).attr("AvailabilityChecker"))
}

$("input[AvailabilityChecker]").keyup(AvailabilityChecker.bind(this));

var AvailabilityChecker2 = function (ev) {  
  console.log("2-DOM", this.getAttribute("AvailabilityChecker"))
  console.log("2-JQ",$(this).attr("AvailabilityChecker"))
}

$("input[AvailabilityChecker]").keyup(AvailabilityChecker2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input AvailabilityChecker="aaaa">
```